# dataclass to json with specific variable name

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a data structure, I want to turn it into a json. Here my classes:

```
@dataclass
class RType:
    type_name: str

    class Meta:
        name = '@r_type'
        content = 'type_name'


@dataclass
class Options:
    type: RType
    content: str

    class Meta:
        name = 'options'
        content = 'content'
```

What I want to get in the result (we always have `r_type` in nested and normal structures):

```
{
'@r_type' : 'init',
 'options': {
   '@r_type' : 'options',
   'options' : 'some_options'
}
```

another example

```
{
'@r_type' : 'dir_init',
 'directory': {
   '@r_type' : 'directory',
   'directory' : 'path_to'
}
```

The problem is that we can easily convert a regular class to json using `addict` or libraries, but my variable name contains `'@'`

How can I do this? (ideally without using libraries)

Comment: How would you do it without libraries if the variable names didn't contain `@`?

Comment: Those are just your base types.  That's not your data structure, which would be a tree of those objects.  You just need to convert that tree to a big dictionary, and pass that to `json.dumps`.

Comment: Your structure doesn't make sense.  Why isn't the data element of the `Options` class called `options`?  `@r_type` isn't a class, it's an element.  What's the type of the outer object?  You need to show us an example of a whole tree.

Comment: @mkrieger1  like that  `x = RType("hello")  json.dumps(dataclasses.asdict(x))`

Comment: @tim-roberts Right now I only have a json that looks like the one in the post (I added another example json that might be) I'm trying to reconstruct from this json what the dataclasses might look like if I wanted to serialize them and get a json.

Comment: @goGOgo the example actually is unclear because I have no idea where the `'@r_type' : 'init'` is coming from - can you update to clarify?

Comment: @rv-kvetch As I already mentioned all these are reqests to the server (which will then send a response) Apparently the server, using this field r_type determines the type of request which was sent to it (for example init - initialization)

Comment: The data structure above doesn't make any sense, as previously mentioned. I have no idea how you got the result from such a dataclass model. For example, where are the `type_name` field or the `content` field in the result?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you ask in a mostly sane manner.  The issue I have with your structure is that `RType` is not an object type.  It's just an attribute of your other types.

This modification of my original script adds a function to move the `r_types` value to the front of each dict.  This is not a completely general solution; if you have lists nested in lists, it will need changing.  As it is, it works with dicts, or with lists containing dicts.

But your JSON reader is defective.  You should file a bug report.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
import json

@dataclass
class Options:
    options: str
    r_type: str = "options"

@dataclass
class Init:
    options: Options
    r_type: str = "init"

def movetypes(dct):
    newdct = {}
    if 'r_type' in dct:
        newdct['@r_type'] = dct['r_type']
    for key,value in dct.items():
        if key == 'r_type':
            continue
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            value = movetypes(value)
        elif isinstance(value,list):
            value = [movetypes(v) for v in value]
        newdct[key] = value
    return newdct

x = Options('some_options')
y = Init([x])
dct = asdict(y)
print(dct)
dct = movetypes(dct)
print(dct)
js = json.dumps(dct)
print(js)
```

Output:

```
{'options': [{'options': 'some_options', 'r_type': 'options'}], 'r_type': 'init'}
{'@r_type': 'init', 'options': [{'@r_type': 'options', 'options': 'some_options'}]}
{"@r_type": "init", "options": [{"@r_type": "options", "options": "some_options"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I really care about the order in which all this data is located. (everything has to be exactly as in my examples, because it is a request and otherwise the server just doesn't recognize it)
What about the order?

Comment: Also, this hack with the substitution of the word for another does not look very cool. Can we fix it? I'm thinking of introducing another class - constructor of such tree data (something like master class)

or functions :
`create_class(type, atrubutes):
 return ({
'@r_type': type,
atrubutes
})`
Where the attributes can be our classes

Comment: If your parser cares about order, then it is in violation of the JSON standard.  That would be a huge bug, and I find it very hard to believe.

Comment: The string replacement is really the right solution.  If you're worried about false positives, look for the quoted value: `.replace('"r_type"','"@r_type"')`.  Coolness is irrelevant.  It's hard to argue with "working".

Comment: Okay thx! but whats about order?

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a solution without libraries, but here's a clean way which actually looks Pythonic to me at least. This does make use of an external library, `dataclass-wizard`. The `json_field` is synonymous usage to `dataclasses.field`, but specifies an alias used for (de)serialization.

Note also: I've needed to swap the order of the fields, so that requires declaring `options` field as an optional field. Since dictionary order should be the order in which the dataclass fields are defined, this ensures `@r_type` shows up first in the serialized dict result.

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # note: can be removed in Python 3.10

import json
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import asdict, json_field


@dataclass
class Init:
    r_type: str = json_field('@r_type', all=True, default='init')
    options: Options | None = None


@dataclass
class Options:
    r_type: str = json_field('@r_type', all=True, default='options')
    options: str | None = None


x = Options(options='some_options')
y = Init(options=[x])
dct = asdict(y)
# print(dct)
# {'@r_type': 'init', 'options': [{'@r_type': 'options', 'options': 'some_options'}]}
print(json.dumps(dct, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "@r_type": "init",
  "options": [
    {
      "@r_type": "options",
      "options": "some_options"
    }
  ]
}
```